# How can I insert tabs 4 spaces-wide and delete them by two spaces?

Tags: c++, vim, indentation

I like this type of indentation in C++:

- indents are 4 spaces wide,
- except for `private`/`public`/`protected` specifiers, which are indented only by 2, and do not alter the indentation of following lines.

Example:

```cpp
class A {
    int x;
  public:
    int y;
}
int func() {
    return 1;
}
```

Therefore I would like

- <kbd>Tab</kbd> to insert indentation spaces 4 by 4,
- <kbd>Backspace</kbd> to delete indentation spaces 2 by 2,
- shift commands <kbd><</kbd> and <kbd>></kbd> should still act of a 4 spaces basis.

To clarify, I am not and will not use real tab character. Only spaces.

Comment: Apart from the motivation, what does this have to do with c++?

Comment: @cigien , comments or answers about why doing what I request could be stylistically wrong in c++ in not impossible I guess. However feel free to remove the tag, if you think it's totally irrelevant, even for those who could/would like to express an opinion on why I should not use this style.

Comment: Those comments would be opinion based. It's fine to ask how to set, or use a particular format, but asking if it's good style, is a bit too subjective. Anyway, I answered with a c++ comment as well :)

Comment: @cigien oh, that's you! I'll try later and accept it.

Comment: Is not this done by cino-g option in cindent? For example :set cinoptions=g2

Comment: @Dmitry, feel free to write an answer, and I'll accept it.

Comment: Wow, I didn't realize I was *seeking recommendations for books, tools, software libraries, and more*. Impressive.

Comment: I deleted my vim answer (which was probably wrong). Since this is tagged `c++`, I would suggest not tweaking vim, and instead use a c++ aware tool like clang-format.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be done by `cino-g` option when using `cindent`. For example, add this line in `.vimrc`

```
:set cinoptions=g2
```

Also read following help topics to see more about C/C++ indenting:

```
:h C-indenting
:h 'cinoptions'
:h cinoptions-values
:h cino-g
```

Comment: This seems actually the cleanest solution. It also removes the necessity of backspacing by 2 spaces, as the access specifiers are automatically indented back by 2 spaces when inserted.

Answer (score 1):

Although the question is probably more about C++ formatting tools, but, anyway, this is how you can do it in Vim:

> Tab to insert indentation spaces 4 by 4
>
> shift commands < and > should still act of a 4 spaces basis

```
" < and > move to the next 'multiple of four' cursor position
set shiftwidth=4 shiftround
" newly inserted tabs follow shiftwidth
set expandtab softtabstop=-1
```

> Backspace to delete indentation spaces 2 by 2

```
inoremap <expr><BS> search('^\s\+\%#', 'bn', line('.')) ? printf('<C-O>%dX', shiftwidth() / 2) : '<BS>'
```

That is, if the cursor is preceded only by spaces then hitting backspace once deletes `shiftwidth() / 2` chars. Otherwise it's just a single backspace.

Comment: +1, however I accepted the other answer as it leveraged the C/C++ context to provide the simplest solution.